# How python suds or sf-suds work with "wsdl:import"?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

For example, i have wsdl in `wsdl_url`:

```
<wsdl:definitions ...>
   <wsdl:import namespace="wsdl/auth/v1/" location="wsdl/auth/v1/soap/auth.wsdl"/>
   <wsdl:import namespace="wsdl/core/v1/" location="wsdl/v1/soap/core.wsdl"/>
   ...
</wsdl>
```

How to call a method from `namespace="wsdl/auth/v1/"`? auth.wsdl contain method login.

```
import suds
client = suds.client.Client(wsdl_url)
client.service.login(...)
```

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/issue/19/add-support-for-importing-xsd-schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a service with both namespace to test, but the logic seems to apply here.

After creating the client, print it. You will have something like below:

```
url = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl"
client = suds.client.Client(url)
print client

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( Weather ) tns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"
   Prefixes (1)
      ns0 = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"
   Ports (2):
      (WeatherSoap)
         Methods (3):
            GetCityForecastByZIP(xs:string ZIP, )
            GetCityWeatherByZIP(xs:string ZIP, )
            GetWeatherInformation()
         Types (8):
            ....
      (WeatherSoap12)
         Methods (3):
            GetCityForecastByZIP(xs:string ZIP, )
            GetCityWeatherByZIP(xs:string ZIP, )
            GetWeatherInformation()
         Types (8):
            ....
```

Then you can set wich service you want with `client.set_options(service='service1', port='port1')`. After that, just call service.function. 
In the example:

```
client.set_options(port='WeatherSoap12')
client.service.GetWeatherInformation()
```

more info: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation